# How to prepopulate entries for a SQL table, so that a first time user gets sample data?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am using Google AppMaker to build a project management tool.

I have a table for 'projects', with the ability to add G-Drive attachments and team members to each instance of a project. I would also like to prepopulate a list of tasks for every new project being created.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: Please refer [Templates](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/) and [Sample Apps](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/) provided by Appmaker as starting point.

Comment: Yes, been there, but there isn't really a valid template. I am looking for a macro or a script that automatically adds a list of tasks each time a new project is created...

Comment: So you won't be getting ready made templates or scripts, try doing it your self first and post your queries here wherever you get stuck.